# Restrict additional pagehead in sharepoint popup window

Tags: javascript

I have added `additionalpagehead` in SharePoint which will run a javascript functions to show some texts.

It is working fine in all the SharePoint pages but it is working in SharePoint popup window also.

How can I restrict it from popup windows?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to check if **IsDlg** query string parameter is not defined. For modal dialogs it is set to "1".

JS code to achieve this client-side:

```
// GetUrlKeyValue is an existant SharePoint function from init.js
var isDlg = GetUrlKeyValue("IsDlg");

if (!isDlg)
{
   // show your text here
}
```